# Retrieving an array of subdcuments (MEAN stack)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a very concrete question.

So I am querying my database using the following (Mongoose call in NodeJS with express):

```
    UserProfileModel.find({'username': req.query.username},'progressmanual' ,function (err, entries) {
            console.log("entries from the server:"+entries);
            res.json(entries);

        });
```

> And this query produces the following result:

```
    { _id: 5580edc16f5d5c3411f703c8,
progressmanual:[ { Date: Tue Jun 16 2015 23:47:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), cups: 5, miles: 5, steps: 6, duration: 6, _id: 5580edd86f5d5c3411f703c9 },
{ Date: Tue Jun 16 2015 23:47:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), cups: 754, miles: 57457, steps: 457547, duration: 54745745, _id: 5580eddd6f5d5c3411f703ca },
{ Date: Tue Jun 16 2015 23:47:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), cups: 547457, miles: 536346, steps: 4436346, duration: 466, _id: 5580ede16f5d5c3411f703cb },
{ Date: Tue Jun 16 2015 23:47:50 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), cups: 436, miles: 6436, steps: 4464346, duration: 446, _id: 5580ede66f5d5c3411f703cc },
{ Date: Tue Jun 16 2015 23:49:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), cups: 5, miles: 5, steps: 6, duration: 6, _id: 5580ee506f5d5c3411f703cd } ], personalgoals: {} }
```

On my front end I am trying to display the entries from the `progressmanual`
so when I try to to do `res.json(entries.progressmanual)` it results in null. Do you know how to extract the array of `progressmanual` objects?

Also, do you know why the query result contains extra "columns" that I didn't request (stuff besides `progressmanual`)?

Comment: *Also, do you know why the query result contains extra "columns"* you didn't tell it **not** to return those columns.

Comment: before the callback i specified 'progressmanual' which is supposed to give me just that. (At least that is what I assumed)

Comment: `-_id` would hide the id, and `-personalgoals` would hide, personalgoals. As far as your main question, it looks like it would work to me, though, i think you're missing the fact that `entries` is an array of entries, not just 1 entry. the console output you copied into the question seems to show only a single entry, but i'm willing to bet it's actually wrapped in `[]`. shouldn't you be using findOne?

Comment: Kevin B, you are right. `findOne()` was the culprit. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Kevin B** from the comments I figured out the problem: changing `find()` to `findOne` allowed me to obtain `entries.progressmanual`. So it looks like `find()` always returns arrays so with `find()` I should have used `entries[0].progressmanual`